# C# Repetitive Evaluation of many Files using Json

Tags: c#, json, algorithm, performance, bigdata

I have written an algorithm to evaluate many Json-Files (average 50 files, every file has average 9mb), this evaluation repeats itself 138 times.
First the data is written into a big 500mb jsonfile, which is then split up to these little files to process the data. Im using JSON.NET for that.
Reading the files isnt timeconsuming at all, but parsing them to a JObject, takes more average 1,5 seconds. Im reading 50 files 138 times, that means im reading the files 6900 times.
One run takes average 4-5 hours, which is way to much to time, time that I dont have ...

To demonstrate what this algorithm is doing, imagine there are 138 unique players and they all played 50.000 games. Now you got these 50.000 games and want to evaluate average values for EVERY player. Now you have to go through these 50 files for every player, when its finished the values are written into a file and the next players evaluation starts. This takes about 1,2-2GB ram for each evaluation, because my algorithm is using functions to fill lists, add values, calculate average values etc. The calculation itself is fast and doesnt need improvements at the moment, I update the code every time to create a faster experience.

Parallelism is used to gather the data from an API, which workes great, but in the case of evaluation it cannot be used, because the files are locked when processed, it would take up to much ram etc.

So my question is, are there any techniques I can process it way faster than now? Processing an average of 6900 files repetitive seems bad practice and wrong, I think im missing something ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without an example of the data, and without at least some code showing us how you're reading the files, it's impossible to make any kind of reasonable suggestion. Update your question with specific examples, and I'll be happy to help you out.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are right. I suggest inserting all data into some storage like MongoDb. It has powerful aggregation framework, that will allow you build requests and indexes to calculate averages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you think there is no other way to do this on a local machine?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. In any case, we need to use some local Db.

Answer (score -1):

Now I have found a solution to my problem ... I reduced the evaluation-time from 5 hours to average 35 minutes. I simply replaced a function of the JSON.net library from Newtonsoft. Parsing the files into a JObject takes about 1.5 seconds each. I just pasted my JSON into http://json2csharp.com/ and it created classes for my json-structure. After that I rebuild my get functions. Since this rebuild it does not take 1.5 seconds anymore, but most likely 0.3 seconds now.

So my tip is to avoid JObject.Parse(string) if you can! It takes more work to do it with the Jsondeserializer but it saves so much time when processing data!

So in summary, I replaced

```
JObject.Parse(string)
```

with:

```
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YOURCLASS>(string);
```

In my case the class is called **RootObject**